# take route parameters and insert in the form

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, routes

Could someone help me, I am using angular and would like to take the parameters of a route and add it to my form. But I don't know how to do that.

example add? name = Fe & age = 15

I would like to take the name and age and fill in my fields, but I don't know how to do this

I'm doing it this way but nothing returns

```
if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['nome, idade, documento']) {
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.form.patchValue({
          nome = params['nome']
        })
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your form is being patched incorrectly. Try one of the following:

```
if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['nome, idade, documento']) {
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.form.get('nome').patchValue(params['nome'])
      });
    }
```

in this case, you are getting the form control you want to patch to (`this.form.get(...`), then patching to the specific control. I normally do this if I only need to patch one value.

or more similar to the method you have so already, with one small change:

```
if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['nome, idade, documento']) {
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.form.patchValue({
          nome: params['nome']
        })
      });
    }
```

notice the colon instead of equals sign. [See Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model)

Comment: in that case it automatically takes the value of my route? no need for a new route in the module routing?

Comment: Based on the information your shared, it should work as needed. I don't think you need a new route unless this throws and error or does not work. For the `this.activatedRoute..` I believe you did everything right

Comment: I do not know if it would be the case, I pass an ngif on these parameters, but I would not be able to activate them without changing the condition and it does not come in the url, do you know what could be or what would solve this?

Comment: I might need a little bit more code to help out with this part of the issue. Is there a chance I could take a better look at your components? Maybe using StackBlitz?

Answer (score -1):

You can not use queryParams to retrieve the params which passed using a pattern like "add? name = Fe & age = 15"

For this pattern, you van use

```
activeUrl:string=window.location.href
```

Then you can decode the activeUrl and retrieve name and age.

if you want to use "queryParams" you should change the url pattern. so something like this:

blablabla.com/page0/Sara/18

The first parameter is Name and the second Age.

Comment: but how would that look inside a patchValue, can you tell me?